# Not able to Spend 2-2 MultiSig UTXO

Tags: transactions, multi-signature, transaction-verification

I created 2-2 Multisig Account `2NECouPA4UVNMzX1K7kekc4W3VudDhMdFkM` from `msrFNhKwLu9GrT3hFoizz21xEwJ61xMsym` and `n1NPFEJHBA8j63B5dgJ3aQcufA8VmrN27U`, I tried spending UTXO from this account but got an error, I was successful in spending UTXO form 2-3 MultiSig Account.

Could someone please help me.

**Address_1:**
Private Key: `89fcbf126a2d78f4055ff4eb4e44642504d2bea1fea248627ca75eaa35dc56eb`

Public Key: `0401e52f885e02000e7ec5f410f2e680cfd0ca8be75d5425c75934499fc17e24152e1f9a391764b858ac276877b56253a7a1beafe8f7574f572461c3780a3778c1`

Testnet Address: msrFNhKwLu9GrT3hFoizz21xEwJ61xMsym

**Address_2:**
Private Key: `b74b1862b7e5e92c4fa9ce79826e1579df1b6b09f1f3bf312918f9e6e32f39de`

Public Key: `044bd79509fea54fc8118eed193a295a34b8dcbd030a09c7fcf815c785846dca56b3d6ddfd96e582a96e6e13e90569dbf8ee52c2517bfbed22f8ad17d850d283b4`

Testnet Address: *n1NPFEJHBA8j63B5dgJ3aQcufA8VmrN27U*

**MultiSig 2-2 Testnet Address**:  `2NECouPA4UVNMzX1K7kekc4W3VudDhMdFkM`

Raw_Script:
`52410401e52f885e02000e7ec5f410f2e680cfd0ca8be75d5425c75934499fc17e24152e1f9a391764b858ac276877b56253a7a1beafe8f7574f572461c3780a3778c141044bd79509fea54fc8118eed193a295a34b8dcbd030a09c7fcf815c785846dca56b3d6ddfd96e582a96e6e13e90569dbf8ee52c2517bfbed22f8ad17d850d283b452ae60f72cc98474313a44b1f4b0c907c2b002ac815a58595a1a28b`

Raw_Transaction:

```
01000000018ba2a19585a515c82a002b7c900c4b1f4ba413434798cc720f36289e812c70c3000000008752410401e52f885e02000e7ec5f410f2e680cfd0ca8be75d5425c75934499fc17e24152e1f9a391764b858ac276877b56253a7a1beafe8f7574f572461c3780a3778c141044bd79509fea54fc8118eed193a295a34b8dcbd030a09c7fcf815c785846dca56b3d6ddfd96e582a96e6e13e90569dbf8ee52c2517bfbed22f8ad17d850d283b452aeffffffff01e0083000000000001976a91490b5f4fc981ff94df22a1f845c0b7074623042d588ac0000000001000000
```

Taking Signature_1 and then Signature_2:
Sig_1: `3044022044ebf0dd5ffe267771987e02a763c3721d4e872931a5b9ec7d05fca0e952dec002205a5315dd4920175ed36d32be7d8011b2d429120bc996408d47e15d4d246982f0`

Sig_2: `304402206574c1e54144268079120ab996d84209edf6bde8620108aab5b1e8ba0a0e7b5b022006b02e6d31459f732d16bf39ea488485c3a7c2d1106c4a9210916df1a9900b73`

Transaction_to_Broadcast:

```
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
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: https://tbtc.bitaps.com/broadcast: mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Operation not valid with the current stack size) (code 16)

https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/pushtx/: Error validating transaction: Rejected script for input 0 referencing c3702c819e28360f72cc98474313a44b1f4b0c907c2b002ac815a58595a1a28b at 0

Comment: What is the value of bitcoin you want to unlock with the transaction described inside the post?

Comment: UTXO value is 0.03148581 and in this transaction, I want to unlock 0.03148. Earlier I have tried 2-3 MultiSig Transaction and faced no problem. I have always encountered a problem when trying to spend from 2-2 MultiSig Address.

Comment: @YashMadhwal can you add the code of the scriptSig, please?

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo I am manually making the transaction from self-created python Programs. I was able to verify 1-1 P2SH, 2-3 P2SH Transaction. I am getting same error for 1-2 P2SH Script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Sign the Raw_Transaction above with private key1.

The output would be

```
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
```

2.Sign the partially signed transaction above with priavate key2.

The output would be

```
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
```

3.Now you can broadcast the transaction signed with two keys